# How can I format multiple languages inside a markdown file differently using Prettier?

Tags: javascript, rust, markdown, prettier

I have a Markdown file that needs formatting.

The Markdown file contains both JS and Rust.

- I would like to format the JS using two spaces, per `prettier` defaults, StandardJS, node style guide, idiomatic JS, AirBnB style guide, MDN, Google Style guide, codepen, jsfiddle, etc.
- I would like to format the Rust using four spaces per `rustfmt`

Here is an example of the markdown file with code that needs formatting:

````
# I am a markdown file

How about that.

Here is some ts

```js
const sayHello = () => {
         console.log(`Hello world`)
}
```

And some Rust:

```rust
fn sayHello = () => {
        println!({}, "Hello world")
}
```

That's all.
````

Here is my `.prettierrc` file. Note I have read [the prettier documentation for overrides](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#configuration-overrides) and I know I am setting overides for file extensions, I could not see a way to specify rust code inside markdown files (which don't have an extension):

```
{
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": [
                "*.rs"
            ],
            "options": {
                "tabWidth": 4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run Prettier (`npx prettier *md`) I can see the output looks like this - **the JS is formatted correctly, but the Rust is not.**

````
# I am a markdown file

How about that.

Here is some ts

```js
const sayHello = () => {
  console.log(`Hello world`);
};
```

And some Rust:

```rust
fn sayHello = () => {
        println!({}, "Hello world")
}
```

That's all.
````

**How can I format multiple languages inside a markdown file differently using Prettier?**